# Foundation framework nested columns

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

super-new to grids and Foundation (I'm using 6.3). I just wanted to check I had this correct, as I was finding it difficult to check against the official documenation.

Basically Im trying to center 8 columns in a row. Then I want two columns within this, one for content and a smaller one for a sidebar.

Initially I created the following as it made sense to me that a large-8 column would then have a large-6 and large-2 within it, adding up to the 8 of the container.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 columns large-centered">
      <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: red;">1</div>
      <div class="large-2 columns" style="background-color: green;">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This did not work, but the following does. Before I continue I wanted to check if this is the correct way of doing what I want to do (so effectively the large-8 and large-4 add up to 12 again, despite being nested within a large-8.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 columns large-centered">
      <div class="large-8 columns" style="background-color: red;">1</div>
      <div class="large-4 columns" style="background-color: green;">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 2nd one is correct. By default, a row has 12 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one will work in most scenarios, but the "Foundation" way of doing what you are asking for (from http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html) is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 large-offset-2 end columns">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="large-8 columns" style="background-color: red;">1</div>
          <div class="large-4 columns" style="background-color: green;">2</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So you have:

---

```
2 col |         8 col          | 2 col
--------------------------------------
      |     8 col     | 4 col  |
```

`.end` simply ends a row without having to specify an empty column to fill up the space, and you need the second `.row` (though it kind of works without it) because you may run into nesting problems further down the line otherwise.